# Finding Green's functions in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, elliptic-equations

[image]

### Attempt

In my book, we have the definition for Green's Function

$$ G(r',r) = \frac{1}{4 \pi } \frac{1}{|r'-r|} + h(r,r')$$

is the Green's function for the Dirichlet problem on some domain of $R^3$ and $h$ is to satisfy the following: $\Delta h(r') = 0$ and $h(r') = - \frac{1}{4 \pi } \frac{1}{|r'-r|}$ for $r'$ in the boundary of the domain. But, we want to satisfy $\Delta G = \delta (x-x_0)$. How do we apply this condition to find our desired Green's Function? Im quite confused how to derive such expressions

Comment: As a reference that might help, all these problems can be solved easily, albeit in a more heuristic manner through the method of images and they have been studied very thoroughly in Physics literature about electromagnetism (see Jackson's electrodynamics).

Comment: Zangwill "Modern Electrodynamics" is also a good physics reference for this type of question.